# How to tidy-up Processing Instructions in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, tidy, htmltidy, marklogic-8

I have a content which is neither a valid HTML nor a XML in my legacy database. Considering the fact, it would be difficult to clean the legacy, I want to tidy this up in MarkLogic using xdmp:tidy. I am currently using ML-8.

```
<sub>
   <p>
      <???&dagger;?>
   </p>
</sub>
```

I'm passing this content to tidy functionality in a way :

```
declare variable $xml as node() := 
       <content>
           <![CDATA[<p><???&dagger;?></p>]]>
       </content>;

xdmp:tidy(xdmp:quote($xml//text()),
   <options xmlns="xdmp:tidy">
    <assume-xml-procins>yes</assume-xml-procins>
    <quiet>yes</quiet>
    <tidy-mark>no</tidy-mark>
    <enclose-text>yes</enclose-text>
    <indent>yes</indent>
  </options>)
```

As a result it returns :

```
<p>
<?  ?&dagger;?>
</p>
```

Now this result is not the valid xml format (I checked it via XML validator) due to which when I try to insert this XML into the MarkLogic it throws an error saying 'MALFORMED BODY | Invalid Processing Instruction names'.

I did some investigation around PIs but not much luck. I could have tried saving the content without PI but this is also not a valid PI too.

Comment: can you give an example of what you expect the processing instruction to look like?

Comment: Please refrain from asking for urgency here - no question may jump the queue, and volunteers do not take well to being rushed.

Answer (score 6):

That is because what you think is a PI is in fact not a PI.
From W3C:

> 2.6 Processing Instructions
>
> [Definition: Processing instructions (PIs) allow documents to contain
>   instructions for applications.]
>
> Processing Instructions
>
> [16]      PI     ::=      '' Char*)))?
>   '?>'
>
> [17]      PITarget       ::=      Name - (('X' | 'x') ('M' | 'm') ('L' |
>   'l'))

So the PI name cannot start with ? as in your sample ??†
You probably want to clean up the content before you pass it to tidy.
Like below:

```
declare variable $xml as node() := 
   <content><![CDATA[<p>Hello <???&dagger;?>world</p>]]></content>;

declare function local:copy($input as item()*) as item()* {
  for $node in $input
   return 
     typeswitch($node)
     case text()
       return fn:replace($node,"<\?[^>]+\?>","")
     case element()
       return
          element {name($node)} {

            (: output each attribute in this element :)
            for $att in $node/@*
               return
                  attribute {name($att)} {$att}
            ,
            (: output all the sub-elements of this element recursively :)
            for $child in $node
               return local:copy($child/node())

          }
    (: otherwise pass it through.  Used for text(), comments, and PIs :)
    default return $node
};

xdmp:tidy(local:copy($xml),
  <options xmlns="xdmp:tidy">
    <assume-xml-procins>no</assume-xml-procins>
    <quiet>yes</quiet>
    <tidy-mark>no</tidy-mark>
    <enclose-text>yes</enclose-text>
    <indent>yes</indent>
  </options>)
```

This would do the trick to get rid of all PIs (real and fake PIs)

Regards,

Peter

Comment: This answer is both valid and complete[and amazingly detailed].  Dear Rachit - play nicely with StackOverflow.. You asked for an urgent response, people took the time to give an amazingly detailed answer. Now please kindly accept the answer. This allows people to understand that the request has been answered and that they can spend their energy on helping others.

Comment: Thanks guys for the impromptu response & Sorry for asking it in urgency. But I am looking after the response from the tidy. It would be great if tidy would have thrown an error rather than creating an invalid xml. 

Cleaning the content won't help me much since the content can be too heavy and that would add to the performance. I would rather like to have it cleansed up in legacy database.

In a nutshell, I want tidy to throw an error saying 'bad or dirty content'. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi Rachit, then you completely miss the point about tidy. Tidy was originally created to automatically fix mistakes in html pages. See https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/ for the explanation. If the main goal is to check for errors you're better off with a decent validator. See https://validator.w3.org/nu/